# How to create Proc without any variables that compares two tables In SQL Developer?

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper, common-table-expression

I skipped Declare statement since it is optional. Got compiler log - error.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE abc
Begin
WITH xT1 AS  
(SELECT    Table1.*
FROM Table1 
WHERE status_CD ='M' )
SELECT 
        CASE  WHEN   Table2.status_cd IS NULL
              THEN 'New'
              ELSE 'Old'
         END AS COMPX
        , xT1.*
FROM Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN  table2
             ON  xT1.t1_ID = table2.t2_ID
;
end;
```

Comment: What is the error?  What do you want to do with the result of your query?  A stored procedure can't simply be a `select` statement.  You could do a `select into` one or more scalar variables, you could do a `bulk collect into` one or more collections, you could declare an `out` parameter that is a `sys_refcursor` and return a cursor to the caller (which would then have to know how to fetch data from that cursor to do something with it).

Answer (score 0):

There is no XT1 table mentioned in your FROM clause. Replace table1 with XT1 in your select statement. below is your modified query

WITH xT1 AS
(SELECT    *
FROM test Table1 
WHERE no =1 )
SELECT 
        CASE  WHEN   Table2.sal IS NULL
              THEN 'New'
              ELSE 'Old'
         END AS COMPX
        , xT1.*
FROM xT1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  test table2
             ON  xT1.no = table2.no
;